# Why will my variable not change when placed in a payload?

Tags: python, variables, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am trying to get a payload value "productid" to +1. But when I use productid+1 the productid variable does not change?

When I run the script the product id stays as "7367" when it should have changed to "7368"

```
productid=7367

headers = {
    "Host": "www..co.uk",
    "Connection": "keep-alive",
    "Content-Length": "121",
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=0",
    "Origin": "http://www..co.uk",
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
    "User-Agent": "Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36",
    "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8",
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8",
    }

payload = {
    "attributes":"",
    "product_quantity":"1",
    "submit":"",
    "product_id":productid+1,
    "show_image_":"0",

}

print ("ProductID:"), productid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`"product_id":productid+1,`

is just incrementing the current value and assigning it to the payload dictionary not back to the productid variable. So further down the page where you have this

`print ("ProductID:"), productid`

you are just printing the original value as the increment you did didn't save to that variable.

To do that you would need to either print the payload product_id variable at the bottom of the script or increment and save back to the variable like this

```
productid += 1

payload = {
    "attributes":"",
    "product_quantity":"1",
    "submit":"",
    "product_id":productid,
    "show_image_":"0",

}

print ("ProductID:"), productid
```

Comment: Thanks! very helpful!

Comment: Can you please elaborate how I can add more numbers, for example +10

Comment: I'm not sure i follow. You can do `productid += 10` to increment by 10 if that's what you mean.

Comment: I am going to run the script multiple times, and each time I need the procuctid variable to go up in increments of 10, does this make sense?

Comment: I see well you should call the script once e.g `python myscript.py` and have a loop in the script that is doing your code above and increment +10 each iteration and that should achieve what you want.